# How to assign ip address to IdTCPServer?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

How to assign IP address to `IdTCPServer` in delphi tokyo 10.2?

I've search many websites and I haven't found what I am looking for.

I'm using the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdContext, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdTCPServer1:=IdTCPServer1.Create(nil);
IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort:=50000;
IdTCPServer1.OnExecute:=IdTCPServer1Execute;
IdTCPServer1.Active:=true;



end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

//message is shown when connection occurs//
showmessage(AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn()); 

end;

end.
```

Comment: The component has a bindings property. It allows to bind the server to one (or more!) of the available IP addresses of the installed network adapters. It is also possible to bind to the IP address 0.0.0.0 to listen on all avalable adapters.

Comment: @mjn42 note that `0.0.0.0` is for IPv4 adapters only. You would need to use `::0` for IPv6 adapters. Indy doesn't support dual-stack sockets (yet), so you would need separate `Bindings` entries for IPv4 and IPv6. By default, if the `Bindings` is empty when the server is activated, default entries for `0.0.0.0` and `::0` are created for you using the `DefaultPort`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it's not what you think, but I use a similar code to assign an ip to a  TCPServer :

```
    ...
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP   := GetIpAddress();
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := GetPort();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
Which IP address are you referring to when you want to "assign IP address to IdTCPServer" and why are you trying to set it?

Normally a IdTCPServer does not need to know it's own IP address.  An IP address of the server is needed by each Client (e.g. the "Public Address") and may not be the same as the address the Server refers to itself as (e.g. If behind a Firewall or Load Balancer).  Different clients may use different addresses to refer to the same server.

Remy's answer regarding bindings refers to the ability for a IPServer to serve requests on a subset of the network interfaces present in the Machine. If you make no specification (Very common), you serve the port on every interface (or 0.0.0.0 for IPV4/ ::0 for IPV6).  If you do do want all interfaces, then you list the local interface IP Addresses in the Bindings as noted by Remy.